# Word Макрос, сторонняя dll, XSLT

Tags: c#, ms-word, xslt

Что делаю:

1. Запускаю макрос Word2013 (который выполняет набор действий)
2. Макрос запускает библиотеку dll, написанную на C#
3. Dll библиотека вызывает Xslt преобразование

Проблема:

1. Когда обрабатывается файл Word с таблицами, внутри которых картинки, то выполнение на макросе прерывается со следующими ошибками:

[image: ][1]]

Comment: Файл Word-а размером 120 мБ, хотелось бы разобраться с ситуацией поподробнее, т.к. много таких документов

Comment: Уточню, ошибка "падает" на Xslt преобразовании

Comment: XSLT версий 1 и 2 читает данные в память целиком, как xml, так и сам xslt. Поэтому для обработки больших данных он мало пригоден. XSLT версии три может поточно обрабатывать данные, но нативного трансформатора под .NET нет. Я бы вообще отказался от xslt и всю работу с xml сделал бы на C#.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что все эти действия выполняются ресурсами Word-а, которые ограничены. Системные требования word к документу можно найти в интернете. Поскольку документ большой, плюс вся эта обработка, вот и получается ошибка памяти. Решением будет выполнять некоторое число процессов не ресурсами Word, например запускать xslt преобразование отдельным потоком... Спасибо.